# How to change position in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a responsive webpage by constructing its bootstrap grid, but after burning hours of searching and trying, I've always end up to nowhere.

Here's my code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" align="center">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <h1 class="border">A</h1>
            <h1 class="border">B</h1>
            <h1 class="border">C</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-9 border" align="center">
        <h1>D</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 border" align="center">
        <h1>E</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Already done the **COL-MD**, like below:

[image]

---

What I'm struggling here is to make it like below when it will **COL-SM**

[image]

I find it really difficult, I have tried offsets, etc. but I can't get the perfect one. Someone can help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `col-sm-12` to define the ABC to be full width when the display is small and `col-md-12` to define ABC each be "full width" in the container, when the display is medium, so it should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12" align="center">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="border col-md-12 col-sm-4">A</h1>
        <h1 class="border col-md-12 col-sm-4">B</h1>
        <h1 class="border col-md-12 col-sm-4">C</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-9 border" align="center">
    <h1>D</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 border" align="center">
    <h1>E</h1>
</div>
```

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79onzx0r/

Output is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: (Ms.) A, B, C does not looked horizontal when COL-SM, it still stays being vertical

Comment: corrected the jsfiddle link and added output. Seems same as in you question?

Comment: I don't know why in your fiddle is okay, but when I test it here using responsive-design-mode of firefox it outputs like this https://i.pixxxels.cc/0yd2HMkd/0.png when It's in COL-SM

Comment: is it the version of bootstrap that differs? bdw I'm using **Bootstrap v4.4.1** here

Comment: You can look it up in jsfiddle, its 4.0.0. But i guess this does not make the difference

Comment: now I found out, I change the `d-flex flex-column` to `row` and its working fine. Can you edit your answer? I'll still mark it though